# HockeyApp.Xamarin breaks Android build

Tags: xamarin, build, hockeyapp

Right after adding the HockeyApp.Xamarin package to my Android application in Xamarin my build no longer works because some Resource Ids are incorrect.

I have reverted the changes and the build works again. I add HockeyApp.Xamarin package again and the build breaks (I add no code).

Any thoughts to resolve this?

Regards

Comment: Could you copy and paste the error you are receiving? It'd be a little easier.

Comment: It's a generic NULLReferenceException.

eg. When I try to `var tmpImg = FindViewBy<ImageView>(Resource.Id.someImageResource)`, this returns null to the variable. So when I try to use tmpImg the app throws a NULLReferenceException

Comment: I'm using the *Multi-Dex" option so not sure if that is part of the problem or not.

Comment: Did you make sure to clean and rebuild your project after adding the HockeyApp.Xamarin reference?

Comment: Yes but still breaks